# How do I set up vue config so that build works correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I know this question was asked many times before but I only get partial answers such as

In your `vue.config.js` do

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: 'babel-loader',
    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src'), // make src the root of transpiling, so if your problematic code is under anywhere in src/ Babel will pick it up.
                 //path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src/renderer') // this is the original line which cages Babel within the renderer/ folder.
              ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```

Followed by the OP commenting

> Yes that nailed it. This path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src') was indeed
>   the missing part: <3

[Source](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/200)

I don't have time to go through the whole documentation for [Vue-CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/README.md#webpack) so could someone please explain how can I do an `npm run build` and have an `index.html` in my `dist/` folder **that just works?**

Right now, I simply get a blank page when I open `index.html`

I followed the standard `vue-cli` documentation to get the project set up.

Comment: `vue init webpack my-project`, that's it.

Comment: Except that you link to electron-vue, are you trying to run it in electron app? If so, you should edit your question. For electron-vue use `vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue my-project`

Comment: Are you opening index.html through a web server?  You can't just open the `index.html` file in the browser.  The page must be served by a web server.

Comment: There's no electrons. Sorry. I just used the vue-cli to set up my project. Comments like these are extremely frustrating. If you want, take a look at my project. Try to run it yourself. See if you can build it.

https://github.com/divyanthj/personal-website

Comment: @PatrickSteele, okay, how do I spin up a web server just to serve my index.html?

Comment: One option: [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).  But if you execute `npm run serve`, it should spin up a local dev web server on port 8080 (IIRC) -- or whatever the default port is in the template you used.

Comment: You can use `npm run dev`, it will be hosted on on localhost, I don't remember the port. You can keep the page open while editing, as it should have hot reload enabled out of the box meaning that all changes are applied every time you save your source files. Only use `npm run build` when you want to use the files in production/test server.